# Нужна ли запятая перед как?

Tags: орфография

Читатели ждут эту книгу с ещё большим нетерпением": они знают, что в ней о жизни**, как** она есть.
Нужна ли запятая перед КАК?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед "как" нужна, так как  с этого слова начинается придаточное предложение

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, так лучше: "Читатели ждут эту книгу с ещё большим нетерпением": они знают, что в ней рассказано о жизни как она есть.

Тогда "как она есть" не обособляем, это устойчивое выражение со значением "правдиво".